# 504 Gateway Timeout on HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, load-balancing

I configured an AWS Load Balancer.  It is working find on HTTP, but when I try over HTTPS I get a 504 Gateway Timeout Error.  I tried all the suggestions on AWS's help page (increase idle timeout), but no luck.  Any ideas why it wouldn't work over HTTPS, but still work over HTTP?

Comment: Probably better to ask this on ServerFault. http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Do you have the https record on the loadbalancer connect to https or http on the instance?

Comment: Https connects to Https on the instance

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the security group for the instance you're connecting to from the loadbalancer has both HTTP and HTTPS allowed from the loadbalancers security group
2. Make sure the load balancer has both http and https Listener rules added.
3. Then point the Load Balancer Protocol https rule at port 80 (http) on the instance to verify it works.
4. If you also have https on the instance and want to have the traffic between the ELB and instance encrytped point it at the instances https

Comment: 1. Yes, both the Instance and Load Balancer security groups have HTTP and HTTPS enabled
2. Yes, the load balancer has HTTP and HTTPS listeners (not the LB does not terminate the SSL cert, it has 443 on front and back end port)
3. If I change it to be 443/80 (front/back) it works.
4. I do want it to be 443/443.  But when I set it up this way I get the 504 error.

Comment: @user472292 if you connect directly ot the instance on 443 with https does it work?

Comment: Yes.  Direct (via IP) on the instance over 443 works.

Comment: if you're breifly able alter the instance security group to allow 100% of all TCP traffic from all sources does it start working?  Do you have IP table rules on the instance itself?  Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: If I open up the security group to all it still fails.  No IP specific rules.  I'm using IIS.

Comment: Don't know much about windows servers, but can you view all incoming port traffic to see if the request is being received on the instance at the expected port?  Something like wireshark?

Comment: IF you can determine if it's making to the machin or not you can then look at whatever logs Windows has to tell you why it's being denied.  A 504 after all you've indicated makes me think they port is listining on the instance, getting the request, but borking at the OS or IIS level.  Are the certs self signed?  Do you have the cert chain being served?